# adding a like button for fbconnect in native iOS application

Tags: iphone, ios, fbconnect

I am working on an application where I need to add a like button which once clicked will allow user to like the page. I have found examples but all of them were using old fb sdk. can some one help me in doing so with new fb sdk?

Regards
Pankaj